# Fetch all the content from "GitHub\repo\LicenseAgreement" into a string value in Android

Tags: android

I want to include the `licensing` on `GitHub` into the `application` for displaying in `TextView` by storing it in a `string` in `values`, so that whenever the `License` changes on `GitHub`, the same shall be reflected in the `application`. Is there a beginner-friendly way to do so?

Assume the link to license text is this: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/repo/main/LICENSE`